# Restrict user access to GPU

Tags: restricted-access

I wish to restrict access to using a GPU (in terms of reserving memory on it) for certain users on a jointly used workstation. So if a user tries to access the GPU on SSH, for example via CUDA, that request would be denied. Any ideas where to start looking for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a group `cuda` to your Ubuntu, then set `750` permissions on the `/dev/nvidia*` devices and change the group ownership to `cuda`. Add those users that are granted to use the GPU to the group `cuda`. There are also driver parameters that do this for you during loading the nvidia driver. ( `NVreg_DeviceFileGID` and `NVreg_DeviceFileMode` ).

Comment: @Thomas thank you very much, that's awesome! If you convert your comment into an answer, I could accept it... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a group *cuda* to your Ubuntu, then set *750* permissions on the */dev/nvidia** devices and change the group ownership to *cuda*.
Add those users that are granted to use the GPU to the group *cuda*.

There are also driver parameters that do this for you during loading the nvidia driver. ( `NVreg_DeviceFileGID` and `NVreg_DeviceFileMode` ).

Comment: why after change "test -c /dev/nvidia${devid} || mknod -m 750 /dev/nvidia${devid} c 195 ${devid} && chown :<group_name> /dev/nvidia${devid};" group_name come to root ?

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko: I think best would be to ask a new question for this

Comment: already)  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727386/change-nvidia-device-files-via-modprobe-d-nvreg-devicefilegid-not-changed