# Restrict Nvidia GPU access to certain users

Tags: drivers, nvidia, permissions, gpu

I have a box with multiple GPUs running ubuntu 16.04. The box is going to have multiple users running different experiments and I need to restrict access to the GPUs so that only certain users have access to certain GPUs. As suggested on [Restrict user access to GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893528/restrict-user-access-to-gpu) I've tried changing the group and permission of the `/dev/nvidia*` files however, when a new session is opened they revert back to their original settings. I've also created `/etc/modprode.d/nvidia.conf` which contains `options nvidia NVreg_DeviceFileGID=120` but this doesn't work either. Am I placing `nvidia.conf` in the wrong place or is the syntax wrong? Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

As @TadejP suggested I have edited `etc/rc.local` to include:

```
chmod 666 /dev/nvidia5
chgrp nvidia_5 /dev/nvidia5
/bin/usr/nvidia-persistenced --persistence-mode --user <USERNAME> --verbose
```

However, this doesn't work. As soon as I start `nvidia-smi` the device files revert to their previous state.

Answer (score 1):

No other instruction worked for me also so we can put commands to do stuff after reboot.
For instance to limiting only second card put commands in /etc/rc.local:

```
chmod 660 /dev/nvidia1
chgrp cuda /dev/nvidia1
```

Other users not in group `cuda` will not even see device with `nvidia-smi`.
Further instructions to use /etc/rc.local:

- [After upgrade to 16.04 LTS rc.local is not executing a command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765120/after-upgrade-to-16-04-lts-rc-local-is-not-executing-a-command)
- https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd

Comment: I tried this and upon starting nvidia-smi the group reverts back to its original state. I also tried starting the `nvidia-persistenced` daemon after the above statements in `/etc/rc.local` however this didn't work either.